# Trouble with using multiple actions within a if statement

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

everytime i code using multiple actions, it doesnt produce and output and the code doesnt work at all until i give it one action alone instead of three, i dont know whats wrong with it, i tried to put this code in if statements and/or just left it alone as an action when pressing the save button

heres the code \ btw im using visual studio 2012

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim Path1 As String = "Backups\"
    Dim Path2 As String = rtbTitle.Text + "\"
    Dim FullPath As String = Path1 + Path2
    Dim textfileTitle As String = "title.txt"
    Dim textfileDescription As String = "description.txt"
    Dim textfileTag As String = "tag.txt"
    Dim textfileChannel As String = "channel.txt"


    If Directory.Exists(FullPath) Then
        rtbTitle.SaveFile(FullPath + textfileDescription, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        rtbDescription.SaveFile(FullPath + textfileDescription, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        rtbTag.SaveFile(FullPath + textfileDescription, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect all values and to see what happens. Also, use the `Path` class, especially `Path.Combine` to build your paths.

Comment: Also you can break on all "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" exceptions in Visual Studio.

Go to Debug-->Exceptions menu, and when the dialog comes up, check the "Thrown" column for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

Answer (score 1):

Add Option Explicit and Option Strict to the top of your code file (or set them as defaults) and you'll soon see where you're getting into trouble.

One problem that will show up is that you're using '+' to concatenate strings, you really should use '&'. You may unwittingly have typos in your control names or be inputting bad data for the paths. All these sorts of errors are covered up until run time unless you set those options.

After that add a Try...Catch block around your code, run it and view the error.